# mysql query that will return the average of posts users created by monthly, and weekly

Tags: mysql, sql

posts table:(id ,user_id, title, created_at)

I need to write a mysql query that will return the average of posts users created by monthly,
and weekly.
The columns should be: user_id, monthly_average, weekly_average.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to divide the total by the number of weeks.  That might be something like:

```
select user_id,
       count(*) / count(distinct yearweek(created_at)) as week_average,
       count(*) / count(distinct year(created_at), month(created_at)) as month_average
from t
group by user_id;
```

This only counts periods that have at least one post.